# 64-bit Quicktime Question

Tags: objective-c, 64-bit, quicktime, sample, macos

Does anyone out there know if there is a way to pull raw, still-compressed audio and video samples out of a Quicktime .mov file using an Apple API / Framework targeting the Mac that can be compiled natively in 64-bit (IE: QTKit)? I know this functionality is available in Apple's QuickTime Framework that targets the Mac, but this Framework can only be compiled under 32-bit.

If anyone is familiar with such a Framework and any related sample code, some insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: similar question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843702/export-every-frame-from-a-movie-using-quicktime-api

Comment: Not the same question, this one is for extraction of compressed frames, the other one is for decoded frames.

Answer (score 2):

The AVFoundation framework released with OSX 10.7 (Lion) can extract raw compressed frames from a movie. This is an ObjC framework with 64-bit support.

See the documentation for the [AVAssetReader class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReader_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009515).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Handbrake source yet?  It may give you some hints.

It is not an Apple API specifically but the codebase is open source and does compile on OS/X Lion and Tiger.  We've been tweaking it to run on native 64-bit windows and OS/X boxes and it does perfectly well reading the .mov files we've thrown at it.

http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.